Saving a file artefact from an Android test after a test run
I'm debugging a video encoder app and need to check the produced file on my laptop, not in the emulator. Currently, I'm saving the resulting file to the temporary folder on the Android device, then I use the Device Explorer to save it to my local machine.
This is cumbersome because I have to synchronize the file list after a test run and this resets my current position in the file tree. I need to click through about 5 folders to find my test folder and my test file.
Is there an option to send a file to the development machine from the emulator, or at least keep current path in the Device Explorer when synchronizing contents?
I suppose that sending a file from emulator to the development machine may be possible because it sends assertion results when running tests.

From a shell one could adb pull <android path> <local path>.  It is also possible to run a test from the shell: adb shell am instrument -w

@Computable thanks a lot. I believe that's the answer

@Computable it seems it was too early to claim a victory. The app folder seems to be removed from the emulator when test finishes. If I put a breakpoint during the test run and try to perform adb pull, I get a failed to stat remote object: Permission denied error. Saving file to the public Downloads folder solved the problem. val outputFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).resolve('test.mp4')

(When running from studio/gradle by default the app is uninstalled after a run).  If running from shell it is not uninstalled; however when running from studio a later gradle version allows that to be "feature" to be turned off here .  However there may be ramifications in your tests if the apk is not uninstalled (i.e. side effects from prior tests).
